# How to display message after form submit and be idempotent

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, idempotent

when a form is submited that inserts a record into the database and the operation was successful, I do a redirect and then pass some parameters in the Url to display the newly inserted record along with a header message (i.e., "Insert was successful").

`response.sendRedirect(yPage + "?pid=" + ipd + "&feedback=" + form.getFormFeebackSB() );`

I would then display in jsp like:
`<c:out value="${param.feedback}" />`

I use a redirect instead of a forward because I want the operation to be idempotent.  When I used `forward` users who hit refresh after a successful insert most often always clicked retry on the warning popup and it resulted in duplicate inserts.

Our IT department then discovered that I had a XSS vulnerability:

`page.jsp?feedback=%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%3Ealert%28%27xss%27%29;%3C/script%3E`

So I changed to this:
`<c:out value="${param.feedback}" escapeXml='true'/>`

but now any `<br>` in my FeedbackSB get escaped and I end up with a header message as such

`Insert was successful<br>An email was sent to Joe<br>Now Complete the XYZ Form;`

what is the standard way to pass messages back to user, while keeping any submits idempotent and protecting against XSS?

## EDIT:

I searched Flash Scope and came across this http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2011/01/implementing-flash-scope-in-java-web-applications/
Since my application would require a lot of work to incorporate a framework, the filter mentioned in that link was easy to incorporate and was able to implement  flash scope with very little effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass the message itself in a redirect. Store the message under a unique key in the session, redirect with the key of this message as URL parameter, then go to the session, get the message, and display it.

I would also remove the message from the session immediately: if the user refreshes, there is no reason to tell him again that the insert was successful.

Most of the MVC frameworks do that for you, using what they usually call a Flash scope (session attributes that are removed from the session as soon as they've been retrieved).

Comment: Nice. I may have to roll my own since I'm not using any Framework. Or is it possible to plug one in without much refactoring?

Comment: Note that the unique Flash scope key is usually passed by a cookie instead of a request parameter. The cookie is obviously removed after the redirect.

Comment: @jeff: it all depends on the design you already have, but I would say no: you'll have many things to change. If you're still at the beginning, I would choose a framework, though: you'll gain much time, won't reinvent the wheel, and have a well-structured application.